# Instructions inside a condition between long long unsigned integers doesn't execute

Tags: c++

In the following code I'm trying to find find the highest p (p is integer) number where 45^p is a divisor of n! (n is integer).

```
int n = 14;
long long unsigned int fact = 1;

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    fact *= i;
}


bool until = true;
int ans;

// for goes until x is greater half of factorial
for(int i = 1; until; i++){

    long long unsigned int x = 1;
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){    
        x *= 45;
    }


    if(fact/2 < x){
        until = false;
    }
    else{
        if(fact % x == 0){
            ans = i;
        }
    }
}

cout << ans;
```

}

However, when I'm trying to end the loop at where x is greater than the half of factorial, it just keeps going on until 45^7 for some reason and it should stop at 45^5, where the number is lesser than half of n!. Why does this happen?

P.D: I'm not saying the program doesn't return the number I want (it returns ans = 2, which is true), but it's just pointless to keep on calculating x.

Comment: What happens when you print `fact`, `fact / 2`, and `x` inside the loop?  You can also print `fact/2 < x` and `until` (using `std::boolalpha` may help readability).

Comment: Adding logging, using a debugger and stepping through code, or adding asserts are three good ways to figure out why code does not behave the way you expect it to.

Comment: Why do you think it should stop at 45^5? 45^7 is the correct limit if n is 15. (Note also that this problem can be solved much more simply: Work out with pencil and paper how to determine the number of powers of 45 that divide into a factorial. Hint: Look at prime factors.)

Comment: @pm100 no because it would stop at the lowest i value, I need the biggest i value

Comment: @RaymondChen I forgot to put into the code, n is 14

Comment: Adding to @RaymondChen's comment, use [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula).

Answer (score 2):

If you need the biggest value, starting from `x = 45` and with `x > fact / 2` the only way out of the loop, you have to get to at least the logarithm in base 45 of `n! / 2`.

And that's a limit of 7 because `45**6 <= 14! / 2` and `45**7 > 14! / 2`.

Pen and pencil as suggested by @Raymond Chen is the way to go.